# CSS background image scales differently than <img>?

Tags: css, image, image-scaling, responsive-images

This is my first question here, so please excuse if my question may not be on point.

On a photo reportage I have around 30 high res pictures which I loaded over CSS as I thought it might have speed advantages over using 'img' tags.

Here's the code for one of the 30 pics:

```
.image-bg-fixed-height2 {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background: url(../Snapshots/Adasevci_02.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
    background-color: #000;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

However in the HTML when I use the 'img' tags specified in the CSS like

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

The images with the CSS approach and the 'img' scale differently. The 'img' seems squeezed on mobile devices. I want the pictures to behave like over the CSS class.

```
<aside class="image-bg-fixed-height2"></aside>
<img src="http://www.jagaland.de/moteladasevci/Snapshots/Adasevci_02.jpg" border="0" class="image-bg-fixed-height2" width="1920px" height="1080px" alt="This is the alt text 2">
```

It looks great and is responsive with the CSS approach but I lose the SEO feature via alt text which is a no go for my photo reportage.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `<img>` with css `width:100%` or `max-width:100%;` then it will automatically squeeze so you can manage it in responsive with removing `width:100%` to `auto` but the best is you can use it in background css with css `background-size:cover;`

Answer (score 0):

The [`object-fit` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) does that, but is not supported at all on Internet Explorer (source: [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit)).

You can use [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) to check browser capability, and use [this script](https://medium.com/@primozcigler/neat-trick-for-css-object-fit-fallback-on-edge-and-other-browsers-afbc53bbb2c3).
This will use the image `src` property as `background-image`, and will perform something similar.